# Using Google Maps API, how do I restrict accuracy when reverse geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I would like to limit the accuracy of a call to `GClientGeocoder.getLocations` so that it only returns results with accuracy of say 0 to 3, that is from unknown to sub-region.

The idea is to find the rough area in which the user clicked.

Answer (score 1):

getLocations() returns a response which contains an array.  Walk the array until you find a placemark with the desired level of detail.  For example, assuming your callback from getLocations() has a response parameter, use the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<response.Placemark.length; i++) {
  if (response.Placemark[i].AddressDetails.Accuracy < 4) {
    alert(response.Placemark[i].address);
    break;
  }
}
```